# Problem with loading masks (VGG Image Annotator) for Mask-RCNN

Tags: python, json, neural-network, conv-neural-network

### Problem

I want to train a MRCNN to detect 2 new classes (bottom, bowl) using pre-trained COCO weights. I have about 400 images already masked in VGG Image Annotator which I can not load. I think there is an issue with classes and polygons that I created, but because there is more than 400 images I really do not want to start from scratch.

Basically I am using code by matterport
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

### Error

During reading .json file with classes and polygons I am having error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Test.py", line 302, in <module>
    train(model)
  File ".\Test.py", line 170, in train
    dataset_train.load_meooow(args.dataset, "train")
  File ".\Test.py", line 115, in load_meooow
    num_ids = [int(n['class']) for n in objects]
  File ".\Test.py", line 115, in <listcomp>
    num_ids = [int(n['class']) for n in objects]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'bottom'
```

I understand that, script is trying to convert 'bottom' into int which is illegal and that is why I am having that error.

I presume there is something wrong with my masks but because there is lots of them, I hope there is something I can do about that...

For me it looks like there is some issue with .json file structure, but I do not see what is wrong.

### Example of polygons for an image

Below polygons for one of the images (2 classes)

```
3D_3_14 (4).jpg2371607":{"fileref":"","size":2371607,"filename":"3D_3_14 (4).jpg","base64_img_data":"","file_attributes":{},"regions":{"0":{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[11,40,200,370,616,761,823,996,1268,1399,1565,1672,1818,1847,2078,2231,2379,2455,2468,2585,2583,7,11],"all_points_y":[1093,1053,984,942,929,916,1002,1022,1009,1058,1051,1049,969,909,918,949,973,1000,1033,1035,1940,1938,1093]},"region_attributes":{"class":"bottom"}},"1":{"shape_attributes":{"name":"polygon","all_points_x":[4,2590,2585,2463,2448,2319,2137,1982,1838,1849,1825,1818,1639,1428,1160,956,867,718,632,576,639,676,714,756,448,297,131,11,4],"all_points_y":[9,9,1035,1038,993,958,925,916,909,827,778,698,552,463,390,341,346,401,486,572,705,774,856,914,933,958,1009,1071,9]},"region_attributes":{"class":"bowl"}}}}
```

### Masking...

During masking sometimes I changed classes order. By that I mean sometimes class bottom was class 1 and bowl was class 2

```
1 bottom
2 bowl
```

and sometimes bowl was class 1 and bottom was class 2

```
1 bowl
2 bottom
```

When there was something covering class bowl, I had to split it into 2 polygons but with same name. So I have in VGG 1 bottom, 2 bowl, 3 bowl.

```
1 bottom
2 bowl
3 bowl
```

Might be that an issue or as long as I stick with correct label for polygons I am ok?

### Tags

I could not use tags like rcnn, mrcnn, mask-rcnn because it requires at least 1500 reputation.. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to annotate class name as an integer string '1', you can try the following code as I did in my case:

```
classes_name = ['bottom', 'bowl']
num_ids = [classes_name.index(n['class']) + 1 for n in objects]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is because of adding class in VGG. In my case, while annotation I used class name in place of class number. 
Remove class name nd replace it with class number. In your case replace
bottom with 1 and bowl with 2 while annonatating in VGG